# Generate a diawi link for testing purpose for flutter iOS project

Tags: ios, flutter

I have developed a project in flutter, and can generate a debug build for client testing, but i am not able to generate a diawi link that i can share with client for testing purpose. I am able to run the project in iPhone and can test it by my self, but i need to generate a diawi link to share the same with client, so that client can test it. Can somebody please guide me how to generate a diawi link for iOS project of Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

To create a diawi distribution link you need to create a IPA file.

Open your project Runner.xcworkspace in Xcode and create a archive. If the archive is successful then export archive to IPA file. You can upload this IPA file

Please check full details in flutter support  - https://flutter.io/docs/deployment/ios

Comment: Thanks @Anish for your answer, it help me a lot !

Comment: Can we do that without an apple membership?

Comment: For create a IPA file we need a apple developer account